# How to use the same kde used by seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, seaborn, kernel-density

I'm trying to use kernel density estimator to obtain the distribution of my data. Using the seaborn, I can simply call `sns.kdeplot(temp, shade=True)` and that will plot the kde or the distribution of my data. However, with seaborn, I cannot obtain scores for new data points. However, if I'm using the sklearn library, I can simply call `kde.score_samples(data)`. Therefore, how can I achieve the same thing with seaborn? Or, is there a way I can return the kde obtained from seaborn?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the documentation https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/a9577e705023873de7c7bbf3e9b6ae0dc1880b51/seaborn/distributions.py#L2641, the bandwidth of the kernel is calculated as: `bw = stats.gaussian_kde(a).scotts_factor() * a.std(ddof=1)` Consequently, I've used the bw with kde from sklearn as: `kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=bw).fit(temp.reshape(-1, 1))`.

Thus, now I'm able to call: `kde.score_samples(x_axis.reshape(-1, 1))`.